# How can I disable auto complete for typescript in vscode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

When I code in typescript in vscode, I see the auto complete popup (as shown below) which is not very usefule. I think they are from another extension but I don't know which one gives me such suggestions. I still need auto-complete from my code.

[image]

Does anyone know which extension does this? How can I disable it?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To disable automatic suggestions when you type, set `"editor.quickSuggestions": false`. If you only want to disable this behavior in TypeScript files, instead add a language specific setting:

```
"[typescript]": {
    "editor.quickSuggestions": false
}
```

If you want to disable all TypeScript support, search `@builtin typescript` in the extensions view and then disable the `JavaScript and TypeScript Language Features Extension`

Comment: I don't want to disable auto-complete completely. I'd like to disable the one used to popup the suggestion on the screenshot. They are not from my code so I assume they are for some extensions. I still need it to show suggestions for my code.

Comment: Those look like normal [auto imports](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/languages/typescript#_auto-imports). They are not from an extension. You need to provide more details about what you are trying to achieve

Comment: Why do you think they are auto imports? If you look at the content of the popup list, none of them are my code or standard typescript function. I just want to popup standard typescript function or functions I defined.

Comment: It says `auto import` in the suggestion description (look on the right side)